# Does plan cache size plays role in increasing performance of query and how?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select 
    ev.iEventId, ev.iEntityId, ev.chAssignedTo, ev.iSourceId, 
    ev.iStatusId, ev.dtInsertDate,
    case 
       when ev.dtinsertdate > DATEADD(ms,-30,ev.dtinsertdate) 
          then ev.dtInsertDate 
       else DATEADD(hh, 3, ev.dtInsertDate)
    end
from 
    event ev WITH(NOLOCK)
left join 
    vehicle v WITH(NOLOCK) on ev.iEventId = v.iSalesNo 
                           and v.tiRecordStatus = 1 
                           and v.iSiteId = 1359 
                           and ev.iSiteId = 1359  
                           and ev.tiRecordStatus = 1
                           and ev.iEventCategory = 1
                           and ev.iStatusId <> 0
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: What does the query in the question have to do with the title?